# python groupby then some columns keep first others keep last

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
cityid    personid    yearstart monthstart yearend monthend  
1          1           2000       01        2001    02
1          1           2001       02        2001    10
1          2           2001       10        2002    10
2          3           2000       01        2002    12
2          4           2005       08        2006    12
```

Since `person 1` in `city 1` has two terms consecutively, I would like to combine these two rows and get:

```
cityid    personid    yearstart monthstart yearend monthend  
1          1           2000       01        2001    10
1          2           2001       10        2002    10
2          3           2000       01        2002    12
2          4           2005       08        2006    12
```

so each row has a unique key {cityid, personid}.
I tried

`df = df.groupby['cityid','personid'].['yearstart','momthstart'].first()['yearend, monthend'].last()`

but get an error message.

Can I ask how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `agg`:

```
(df.groupby(['cityid','persionid'])
   .agg({'yearstart':'first',
         'monthstart':'first',
         'yearend':'last',
         'monthend':'last'})
)
```